# Is there a visual client for Git on Mac OS X that allows to do interactive rebase graphically?

Tags: git, user-interface

I'm wondering if there is gui app for OSX that allows to do all the functionality of git's interactive rebase in the GUI. I've investigated most of the options available but couldn't find one with this feature.

Answer (score 4):

It's not really a git client but Intellij IDEA has advanced git support, including visual interactive rebasing.
[image: intellij git interactive rebasing]

Answer (score 0):

SourceTree (Atlassian) is free and has a UI for interactive rebase.